# Help with concat in query

Tags: sql-server

How to get this working?

```
SELECT Concat(city, ' ', location, ' ', location2) as src1 
FROM locations
WHERE src1 LIKE '%var%'
```

Comment: Please restate the question more clearly and provide example of wrong output, exptected output and (possibly) table structure/sample data

Comment: SQL Server does not have a `concat` function so you've presumably mistagged this question (or accepted an answer that doesn't work!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Concat( city, ' ', locatio`n, ' ', location2 ) as src1 FROM locations WHERE Concat( city, ' ', location, ' ', location2 ) LIKE '%var%'`
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

How about using the **+** cocantenation operator

```
SELECT  city + ' ' + location + ' ' + location2  as src1 
FROM    locations 
WHERE   city + ' ' + location + ' ' + location2 LIKE '%var%'
```

Have a look at [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

Or you could use a sub select

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  city + ' ' + location + ' ' + location2  as src1 
            FROM    locations 
        ) vals
WHERE   vals.src1 LIKE '%var%'
```

Or using Sql Server 2005+ you could use a `WITH` statement

```
;WITH vals AS(
        SELECT  city + ' ' + location + ' ' + location2  as src1 
        FROM    locations
)
SELECT  *
FROM    vals
WHERE   src1 LIKE '%var%'
```